# Могут ли перемешаться данные в статическом свойстве класса?

Tags: php, ооп, веб-программирование

Представьте, что к серверу происходит почти одновременный одинаковый запрос.

Сервер, при формировании ответа использует статический массив класса, для удобного доступа к нему из разных мест кода.

Есть ли шанс, что в этот статический массив попадут данные, предназначенные для разных клиентов?

П.С. *Я уверен, что нет, но не могу это доказать.*

Comment: Никаких статических массивов для разных клиентов не должно быть в принципе....... статика используется для общих вещей.....например отфильтровать данные пользователя....или конвертировать дату из одной в другую и т.д............. для пользователя должно быть ограничено объектом, к которому нет доступа для другого

Comment: @АлексейШиманский т.е. если создается новый объект, это даёт 100% гарантию того, что он будет использоваться только этим пользователем? И, например, доступ к этому объекту, для удобства, можно сделать через статическое свойство (получится что-то вроде синглтона)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не могут.

PHP архитектурно следует подходу `Shared nothing`, т.е. разделяемых между запросами данных нет. PHP гарантирует, что пока вы сами не станете вводить общую для запросов сущность - например, внешние файлы, механизм сессий, СУБД и прочее - параллельные запросы влиять друг на друга не будут вообще никак, как будто их нет и у вас только один запрос.

Достигается это использованием разных адресных пространств (а обычно - и разных потоков ОС, каждый процесс обычно используемого FPM в один момент времени исполняет только один запрос) для обработки каждого запроса пользователя. Поэтому приходится на каждый новый запрос запускать приложение с нуля, а после завершения обработки запроса все ресурсы высвобождаются. Это одновременно и плюс и минус. Плюс - вы можете не думать о конкурентном доступе (пока не касаетесь внешних по отношению к PHP систем), что сильно упрощает код и избавляет от связанных с параллелизмом ошибок. Принудительное освобождение памяти после запроса позволяет не заботиться о маленьких утечках памяти, важных для длительно работающих сервисов - утечка 1кб в минуту через месяц уже приличная штука. Так же этот подход позволяет без проблем и линейно масштабировать приложение добавлением новых ядер CPU, новых процессоров и целиком новых серверов. Минус - запуск приложения с нуля на каждый запрос всё-таки не бесплатен и это довольно бесполезная операция по своей сути.